# Silverlight - created a new domainservice but how do I access it from client?

Tags: silverlight, domainservices

I have used the SL business application template and added a new blank, empty domain service in my Services folder on the .Web part of the solution. The class is DomainService1 and inherits from DomainService. It contains one method:

```
public class DomainService1 : DomainService
{
    public string Hello()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

How do I access this service method from the client? I can't seem to create an instance of the domain service at all client side.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The client side code is generated by RIA Services.

To access services that inherits DomainService you create a new context on the client side.

Replace the "Service" part of the name with "Context".

UserService = UserContext, ArticleService = ArticleContext etc.

Client code

```
var testContext = new TestContext();
            testContext.Hello();
```

Service code

```
[EnableClientAccess]
    public class TestService : DomainService
    {
        public string Hello()
        {
            return "Hello world!";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have enabled the RIA service for your project.

If your service name ends with a `service` tag then you will be able to convert it to a context
like my service name is `DomainService1` then at client side it could be accessed by `DomainContext1`. If on the server side, my Domainservice name is `ABC`, then I can directly access it by name, there is no need to context.

Service code:

```
[EnableClientAccess]
public class TestService : DomainService
{
    public string Hello()
    {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

Client code:
On the client side you have to to declare a namespace like `system.your web project.web.servicesmodel.client`

Now,

```
TestContext test=new TestContext(); 
test.Hello(getData,null,false);`
```

// first parameter is callback method, the second is not important for you, and the third is if any exception occurs then,

```
public void getData(InvokeOpration<string> value)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(""+value.Value);

    }
```

Now you can get the Hello World as a `MessageBox`.